# how to compress JSON data in vertx

Tags: json, vert.x

is there any way to compress this data in Vertx ?

this is a JSON

```
[["29-01-2015 05:00", "172.16.10.62", 75],["29-01-2015 06:00", "172.16.10.101",74] 
,["29-01-2015 07:00", "172.16.10.62", 75],["29-01-2015 08:00",
 "172.16.10.62", 78],["29-01-2015 09:00", "172.16.10.101", 75]]
```

> can we use `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream; this?`

please tell me

Comment: Can you give more context, is this content to send on an `HttpServerResponse`?

Comment: @tsegismont assume it is same and about 100 mb, that is why i put a demo , i am sending it into R